use jq to pick a key out of a list of a list of objects and raw output with newline separation for outer array items
I want to output a specific key of list of a list of hashes as lines where each outer array item is separated by an empty line. To illustrate:
Input is:
[
  [
    {
      "visible": true,
      "url": "url-1"
    },
    {
      "visible": true
    },
    {
      "visible": false,
      "url": "url-2"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "visible": true,
      "url": "url-a"
    },
    {
      "visible": true,
      "url": null
    },
    {
      "visible": false,
      "url": "url-b"
    }
  ]
]

Expected output is:
url-1
url-2

url-a
url-b

Now, I can get the output I want using the following:
cat input.txt | jq 'walk(if type == "object" then (.url | select( . != null)) end) | .[] | select(length > 0)' | jq 'join("\n")' | jq -rs 'join("\n\n")'

There are two issues here:

Picking the value of a specific key, without destroying the hierarchy and handling potential null values (because the key did not exist, or was actually null) is all handled by the first jq invocation, so we get a list of a list of strings
The second and third invocation turn this into the desired output, a list of (raw) strings, where each URL gets its own line, and the different outer array entries are separated by an empty line.

But it seems like there should be an easier solution for either of those issues, especially for the second one.

$ jq -r 'map(map(.url) | join("\n")) | join("\n\n")' file
url-1
url-2

url-a
url-b

This joins the url strings of all elements of a sub-array with newlines and then joins all of the generated strings from the sub-arrays with double newlines.
This would treat null-valued url strings as empty strings and would output as empty lines.  To avoid this, you may use .url // empty in place of just .url in the jq expression.  This would weed out any missing url values and any such values that are null or false.

I've added some corner cases to the input.
Your command works perfectly, especially using the // empty. Thanks!
Happy to see that at least the double-join was not too far off the mark, but the inline version is nicer. :-)
